# THREE.js object loaded with ObjectLoader unable to change opacity

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, opacity

I have a THREE.js object stored in a JSON file. I want to set the opacity of the object, but nothing has changed, still fully opaque.

I am running on THREE.WebGLRenderer 104, on Google Chrome 76, Windows 10. I have tried all other things I have found on google, and none have changed anything.

```
    loader.load(
        "objects/brain-simple-mesh.json",
        function ( obj ) {
            obj.traverse((node) => {
                if (node.material) {
                    node.material.opacity = 0.5;
                    node.material.alphaTest = 0.5;                       
                    node.material.transparent = true;
                }
            });
            window.group = new THREE.Object3D();
            //reajustments
            obj.rotation.z = -0.5;
            obj.rotation.x = 0.09;
            group.add(window.obj=obj);
            scene.add( group );
            //look at object
            camera.position.z = 10;
            setInterval(function(){
                //rotate object
                window.group.rotation.y+=0.03;
            }, 100);
    },
        function ( xhr ) {
            //progress bar
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('progress').style.width = (xhr.loaded / ( xhr.total > 0 ? xhr.total : 9719635 ) * 100) + '%';
    },
     function ( err ) {
             //error
         console.error( 'An error happened' );
     });
```

I expect to see a semi-transparend brain model, what I am getting is some cheap, ripoff fully opaque one.

URL: http://im--age.rf.gd/u0/Terminal%20Man/

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected your `node.material` objects, I noticed that although transparency was set to true, and opacity was set to 0.5, the `depthWrite` value was still set to true. I then looked at your code and saw you are setting `node.depthWrite = false`. But this needs to be set on the material. Try:

```
node.material.depthWrite = false;
```

This made the difference when I downloaded your JSON and ran your code locally.

So, for example, on the site you linked to, your `obj.traverse()` should look something like this:

```
obj.traverse((node) => {
    if (node.material) {
        node.material.transparent = true;
        node.material.opacity = 0.5;
        node.material.depthWrite = false;  // not node.depthWrite
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, the result was better, but for me it was even more unexpected. i promise i only changed that line, and the result shown in this screenshot [here](http://im--age.rf.gd/u0/download.png)  (also on the website)

Comment: no clue what the white sphere is, maybe something in the JSON file. also wondering why some of the triangles are transparent, and some fully opaque;

Comment: I would say maybe open separate questions for those issues, since this question was specifically about changing opacity using `ObjectLoader`. That said, if you look at the JSON file, there are indeed 2 sphere geometries in it, so that likely explains the sphere. I'm not sure what you mean about triangles not being transparent though.

Comment: [screenshot](http://im--age.rf.gd/u0/download.png) this is an image with the changes that were recommended. i got some triangles at 0% opacity, and triangles with 100% opacity(look at the image)

Comment: Those effects are not related to how to change the opacity of the material. Since you are asking something completely different, please open a new question and include a [minimal, verifiable, and complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your JSON that demonstrates the undesired effect. There are some highly qualified ThreeJS/WebGL experts on here that could probably help.